# i need help append rect a few deep

Tags: javascript, html, svg, append, rect

ok so im trying to append two orange rect within a green rect within a black svg tag. the black works and the green works, however the orange shape does not work. any suggestions on why?
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tetris(test)</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleSheets/main.css">
    <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/jquery.1.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <svg id="container" width= "500" height= "650" style= "background-color: black" position= "relative">
      </svg>

  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var htmlNS = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";

function createRect() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("container");
    var shape = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "rect");
        shape.id = "shape1";
        shape.style.width = "150px";
        shape.style.height = "100px";
        shape.style.fill = "green";
        shape.style.position = "relative"
        elem.append(shape);
        var rec = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "rect");
            rec.id = "box1";
            rec.style.width = "150px";
            rec.style.height = "50px";
            rec.style.fill = "orange";
            rec.style.y = "50px";
            rec.style.position = "absolute";
            shape.append(rec);
        var rec2 = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "rect");
            rec2.id = "box2";
            rec2.style.width = "50px";
            rec2.style.height = "51px";
            rec2.style.fill = "orange";
            rec2.style.x = "50px";
            shape.append(rec2);
}
window.onload = createRect;
```

so within the green rectangle there should be an orange shape that looks like an upside down T. any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can't nest rect elements in SVG. You need to make them all children of the container.

Comment: but i neeed the orange shape to move when i move the green rectangle.

Comment: So move them both in the same function, or put them both in a container and move the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add rectangles inside the SVG tags so I added the line

```
 const svg = document.querySelector("svg");
```

```js
var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var htmlNS = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";

function createRect() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("container");
     var shape = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "rect"); 
 const svg = document.querySelector("svg");
        <!-- shape.id = "shape1"; -->
        shape.style.width = "150px";
        shape.style.height = "100px";
        shape.style.fill = "green";
        shape.style.position = "relative"
  <!-- elem.append(shape); -->
        svg.append(shape);
        var rec = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "rect");
            <!-- rec.id = "box1"; -->
            rec.style.width = "150px";
            rec.style.height = "50px";
            rec.style.fill = "orange";
            rec.style.y = "50px";
            rec.style.position = "absolute";
   <!-- shape.append(rec); -->
            svg.append(rec);
        var rec2 = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "rect");
            <!-- rec2.id = "box2"; -->
            rec2.style.width = "50px";
            rec2.style.height = "51px";
            rec2.style.fill = "orange";
            rec2.style.x = "50px";
            <!-- shape.append(rec2); -->
   svg.append(rec2);
}
window.onload = createRect;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tetris(test)</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleSheets/main.css">
    <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/jquery.1.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <svg id="container" width= "500" height= "650" style= "background-color: black" position= "relative">
      </svg>

  </body>
```

Inside the SVG there is only absolute positioning. Therefore, if you want the orange rectangles to be on top, you need to add them later than the green rectangles

**This is how it looks in the pure  SVG**

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width="500" height="650" viewBox="0 0 500 650"  >  
     
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
 <rect  width="150" height="100"  fill="green" />
  <rect  y="50" width="150" height="50"  fill="orange" />
     <rect  x="50" width="50" height="51"  fill="orange" />
</svg>
```

Comment: but will this allow me to move the green box and also move the orange shape?

Comment: @Joe Misheski You can move any rect by changing its coordinates `x` o r `y`

Comment: Yeah but is there any Way to have a parent rectangle so where I move that all the others move with it to minimize the amount of code I would have to write because what I have here is just an example, my real purpose it’s going to result in much much more

Comment: @Joe Misheski Wrap a group of rectangles use  tag `g`  inside svg this will be the parent container and move it. Do you want me to write an additional example on pure SVG?